# Is it possible to return a AST built using Bison without using a global variable?

Tags: c++, bison

I have an AST ( Abstract Syntax Tree), for a grammer,built using Flex/Bison. Currently, I access the data structure using a global variable.

parser.y

```
%{
      mynamespace::AST * ast;
%}

%%
PARSER
%%
```

I currently build the tree and use it in the following way:

A.hpp

```
#include "ast.hpp"

extern mynamespace::AST * ast;

namespace mynamespace{

extern "C" int yyparse();
extern "C" FILE * yyin;
MyClass A 
{
  void readGrammer( FILE * file)
  {
    yyin = file;
    do{
      yyparse();
    }while(!feof(file))
  }
  void method1()
  {
    //do something with the ast
  }
};
}
```

1. Is there a way of making `ast` a data member of my class and not depend on the global variable ?
2. Also, is it possible to hide Bison/FLex code from the user ?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: It's spelt "grammar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Is there a way of making ast a data member of my class and not depend on the global variable ?**

You can use the `%parse-param` to add one (or more) parameters to the `yyparse` prototype. In particular, you could pass a pointer to `yyparse` and fill it in with the parse result. You probably also want to make `yyparse` "pure" (reentrant). See the sections ["The Parser Function"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Parser-Function.html#Parser-Function) and ["A Pure Parser"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Pure-Decl.html#Pure-Decl) in the bison manual (also possibly available as `info bison`)

Alternatively, you can use the ability of `bison` to generate C++ code, which will effectively do all of that.

**2. Also, is it possible to hide Bison/Flex code from the user ?**

You can insert `namespace {` blocks into the generated code, but it requires a bit of manual (or scriptable) post-generation manipulation. (Concatenating the bison and flex output into a single translation unit, for example.) Not at all difficult, though.